# Вывод JSON данных из объекта в массиве в Pug(Jade)

Tags: json, вывод, jade, хранение-данных, pug

Пытаюсь вывести таким образом:

```
h1.main-title.center Changelog
    each log in changelog
      .changelog-item
        .second-title 
          span= log['ver']
          span.text-hide= log['date']
        .changelog-item__log
          .row
            .col-xs-3
              span.label.label--success= log.do['title']
            .col-xs-9
              span= log.do['text']
```

Json:

```
{
  "log1": {
    "ver" : "1.0.0",
    "date" : " - 31 July 2018",
    "do" : [

      {
        "label" : ".label--success ",
        "title" : "Add",
        "text" : "Changelog Page"
      },
      {
        "label" : ".label--danger ",
        "title" : "Fixed",
        "text" : "Navbar"
      }
    ]
  },
  "log2": {
    "ver" : "1.0.2",
    "date" : " - 31 July 2018",
    "do" : [

      {
        "label" : ".label--success ",
        "title" : "Add something",
        "text" : "Changelog Page something"
      },
      {
        "label" : ".label--danger ",
        "title" : "Fixed something",
        "text" : "Navbar something"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Но кроме как **ver** и **date** ничего не появляется.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: чем компилиш ?.

Comment: @qwabra gulp 3, на компиляции ошибок нету. Данные в обычном объекте выводятся без проблем